# What flag do I use so my activity is launched every single time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-lifecycle, android-intentservice

Currently, in my code I am using an activity that doesn't bring in the layout every single time. I am using the following flags : not sure why it's not going through. Here's my code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_GROUPID, convo.getGroupID());
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and here's my layout that gets called:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);
        App.getComponent().inject(this);
        App.subscribe(this);

        if (getIntent() == null) {
            Timber.e("Missing intent");
            finish();
            return;
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.message_add_to_title);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        isAnswering = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWERING, false);
        isFromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_IS_FROM_NOTIFICATION, false);


        GroupID = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_GROUPID);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(GroupID)) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        myConvo = convoRepository.get(GroupID);
        if (myConvo == null) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // TODO remove constructor arguments

            myFragment = new RoomFragment(myConvo.getAllUsers().size(), isFromNotification);

            if (myFragment != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(
                                R.id.my_fragment_container,
                                myFragment,
                                BaseFragment.class.getSimpleName()
                        ).commit();
                if (!isFromNotification) {
                    checkPermissionAndJoin();
                } else {
                    // Make sure to sure speaker state
                    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(FSM.getInstance().getUIState().isSaveSpeakerOnState());
                }
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what is causing the layout to be suppressed every now and then , when its supposed to launch every single time. In my manifest i have added the launchmode to be singleTop. Should i clear the activity somehow onstop or ondestroy so previous instance doesnt stay open ?

Comment: Every time you call finish and return you're ending the activity without showing anything.  If you don't want that to happen, don't do that.

Comment: but my code doesnt even go to the finish and return blocks in oncreate, every single time in the lifecycle it goes to onstart and then onresume. but when the layout doesnt show, onresume doesnt get called for some reason and automatically ends up with onstop and ondestroy, do u think something in onstart could be causing this?

Comment: @Marissa Nicholas : I am bit confused with your question, Can you please elaborate what exact output you needed, So I can help you.

Comment: I want the layout to show every single time the intent calls it. but apparently it dies down sometimes and ends up in onstop and ondestroy states .

Comment: You are mixing the Activity launch modes and flags! Checkout [this guide on Activity launch modes and flags](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-activity-launch-mode-e0df1aa72242)